# wordpress shortcode render content in dashboard also

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a simple wordpress shortcode

```
function my_recent_post()
{
 echo 'hello';
}
add_shortcode( 'recent', 'my_recent_post' );
```

with the shortcode [recent] and its working fine and visible in front page, 
but the problem is, its printing the *hello* in the dashboard also.
below is the screenshot, can anyone please help.

[image]

**Update:**

I was actually trying to show posts, so can you help me with this, because it renders the lists of posts in the dashboard itself like the "hello". I tried:

```
function lorem_function() { 
    global $post; 
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) : 
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <div> 
        <?php the_date(); ?> <br /> <?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        </div> 

    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    return; 
} 
add_shortcode('lorem', 'lorem_function');
```

Comment: The `echo` inside the function is what is displaying it in your admin. For a shortcode function, you should return the value and WP will automatically display it when the shortcode is used in the content

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten, can you suggest me how to display list of posts with the same concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments to me & Nikita Dudarev, what you need to do is create a variable to hold all the post information and then return it. Using the function you posted as an example:

```
function lorem_function() { 
    global $post; 
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args ); 

    // create a variable to hold the post information
    $html ="";
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) : 
        setup_postdata( $post ); 

        $backgroundstyle = ""; 

        // get the featured image and set it as the background
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // make sure the post has a featured image
            $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' ); // you can change "medium" to "thumbnail or full depending on the size you need
            // add the css for the background image. You can include background-size etc ad required
            $backgroundstyle = "background-image: url('".$imageurl[0]."');";
        }

        // add the information to the variable
        $html .= '<div style="'.$backgroundstyle.'">';
        $html .= get_the_date();
        $html .= "<br />";
        $html .= get_the_title();
        $html .= get_the_excerpt();
        $html .= "</div>";

    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    return $html; 
} 
add_shortcode('lorem', 'lorem_function');
```

Note that `the_date()`, `the_title()` and `the_excerpt()` all display the information (just like `echo`).

Instead you must use `get_the_date()`, `get_the_title()` and `get_the_excerpt()` - these get the same information, but instead of displaying it directly, they return it as a variable which you can then store in your html string to be returned.

**Update:**

As you don't want to use the variable name on each line for whatever reason, you can do it like this:

```
$html .= "<div>".get_the_date()."<br />".get_the_title().get_the_excerpt()."</div>";
```

I'm not sure why you specifically want to change it to do that - it makes absolutely no difference to how it works, it just makes it harder to read and identify any errors :-)

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten , thats working very well, if all this can be done without the variable in each line then it will be awesome.

Comment: You can remove the variable from each line is you wish, just concatenate each section. I'm not sure why that would make a difference though, it will have exactly the same result but will be more difficult to read. I've updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy, don't forget to accept an answer if it was helpful to you, it will close the question on Stack Overflow and show others that this solution works. It can also encourage others to answer your questions in future :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your function must return a value, not output

```
function my_recent_post()
{
 return 'hello';
}
add_shortcode( 'recent', 'my_recent_post' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikita , i recently tried and that works, but actually i was trying to show posts, so can you help me with this, because it renders the lists of posts in the dashboard itself like the "hello"

Comment: I tried 

    `function lorem_function()
 {
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
 <div>
  <?php the_date(); ?>
  <br />
  <?php the_title(); ?>   
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
return;
 }
add_shortcode('lorem', 'lorem_function');`

Comment: @AwsmeSandy Write it all in one variable, which you will then return